# how redux/reselect solve dynamic/arbitrary dependency

Tags: redux, reselect

I'm trying to implement some generic input component, one of the requirement is to be able to validate it base on 'arbitrary expression' like "store.a.length>10 && store.b.something == 'aValue'"

I have to pass the whole store to the component, but it will result in re-render the component whenever the store get update, most of the time, the update is not relevant to the expression, for example store.e is update, but it's not used in the expression at all.

I would appreciate any suggestion how to tackle the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of the connect function in Redux. Dan Abramov has some good tutorials on egghead about it: [generating containers](https://egghead.io/lessons/react-redux-generating-containers-with-connect-from-react-redux-visibletodolist)

Comment: Yes, I'm using connect function. I have to pass the root of the store to the component, as the expression could use arbitrary part of the store. so it results re-rendering on every update of the store.

Comment: you could pass a function as a property to your component. eg) myfunc(data){return data >0} <component validator={myfunc} />

Comment: I am not sure if my last comment answered your problem so to extend on it: in the past I have used a form of 'currying' where I use a factory method to fetch the data and return a function that acts on this data with further parameters to do the actual work. In essence the idea is that the input control does not know how to validate itself, you need to pass in a function or object that the input component can use to validate the input. This 'dependency' can be a function (simplest, as described above), closure or fully instantiated object

Comment: To be-labor my last comment your basic component should not know how to validate itself - the parent form or component should provide the validation rule which the input component can call when necessary. The validation rule would receive a value and return true or false according to your logic and the input control can then render accordingly. You can extend from this basic component by extending it with a series of components with different default validators.

Comment: Many thanks for your labouring explanation :), I think passing in a function  should work. I will give it a try this or next week once I have time.